# How to fill_in datepicker using Capybara, Rails, MiniTest spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest

I have a form_tag that generates the following HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://www.example.com/product_page" id="dates_form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  Min date: <input id="datepicker_mini" name="datepicker_mini" type="text" />
  Max date: <input id="datepicker_maxi" name="datepicker_maxi" type="text" />
</form>
```

The above is ALL of the generated HTML. I have removed any partials and layouts to try and make debugging this issue as easy as possible.

The datepicker fields call on jquery UI datepicker.

I would like to avoid javascript for my test and simply fill in the date fields with text dates. I have tried `fill_in "datepicker_mini", :with => "01/01/2010"` but whilst it does not cause the test to fail it also does not fill in the field when I use `save_and_open_page` to test.

**Update: TEST CODE**

```
it "runs report" do
  login_test_user
  within("#dates_form") do
    fill_in "datepicker_mini", :with => "01/01/2010"
    fill_in "datepicker_maxi", :with => "01/01/2020"
  end
  save_and_open_page
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for the test?

Comment: Added test code. Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible there is a hidden field with the same name somewhere on the page?

Comment: I thought that myself from reading another thread on Stackoverflow but I searched the generated HTML and could not find another instance of datepicker_min.

Comment: I have removed all partials and layouts from my view to make the code as basic as possible and updated this question with the new generated HTML. I still can't seem to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 28):

i had the same problem. After reading the documentation of capybara, my solution was to use page.execute_script() to set a value directly to the input.

```
## fill_in "person_birthdate, with: "21/12/1980"
page.execute_script("$('#person_birthdate').val('21/12/1980')")
```

This a little dirty, i think, but work for me.

Gotchas:

- I used Selenium drive.
- I run the example with js: true
- I used a plugin called zebra to generate the datepickers, but the principle is the same.

Edit: This works for Poltergeist as well

Answer (score 9):

I like this solution:

```
page.execute_script("$('#show_sale_date').datepicker('setDate', '01/01/2010')")
```

Taken from here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: This is great because it makes sure the data picker is loaded and working properly.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to simulate the UI clicks, this works for me (using a javascript driver).

when my datepicker's ID is 'target_date', this navigates to next month, then selects the 15th.

```
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#target_date').trigger('focus') }
page.execute_script %Q{ $('a.ui-datepicker-next').trigger('click') }
page.execute_script %Q{ $('a.ui-state-default:contains("15")').trigger('click') }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It's important that the date is in that format as it won't parse by the date picker otherwise.
`page.execute_script %Q{ $("md-datepicker[name='datepicker_mini'] input").val('2010-1-1').trigger('input') }`

Comment: This is the real answer.  Normal capybara commands work, the format just needs to be in `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Minitest with Capybara, and was able to do the following:

```
fill_in "Starts at", with: "2023-04-22T10:00:00"
```

The formatting matches what is automatically displayed as the value for the field when you use your browser's `Inspect` tool.

Comment: Can confirm, this is the current answer. Not sure what Rails version it changed in, but it's super easy now.

Only challenge I've found is that Capybara couldn't overwrite existing data in the form correctly when the datepicker has an AM/PM field (e.g. ```strftime("%m%d%Y\t%I%M%p")``` would fill the field correctly the first time, but wouldn't overwrite the AM/PM on the second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me. Perhaps because there is no input field on the application I am writing tests for. My solution is a lot uglier, but it picks dates and verifies the selection in a datepicker that is GUI only.

```
##selects 'Custom' option, then specified dates, and verifies that specified dates are displayed.
Then(/^select "Custom" values, "([^"]*)" to "([^"]*)" and verify selection$/) do |arg1,arg2|
  step %{select 'Custom' from timespan drop-down}
  start = Date.strptime("#{arg1}",'%m/%d/%Y')
  start_day = start.day
  start_month = start.strftime('%b')
  start_year = start.year
  stop = Date.strptime("#{arg2}",'%m/%d/%Y')
  stop_day = stop.day
  stop_month = stop.strftime('%b')
  stop_year = stop.year
  within('.left.hasDatepicker') do
    find('.ui-datepicker-year').click
    find('option', :text => start_year).click
    find('.ui-datepicker-month').click
    find('option', :text => start_month).click
    find('.ui-state-default', :text => start_day, :match => :prefer_exact).click
  end
  within('.right.customdatepicker') do
    find('.ui-datepicker-year').click
    find('option', :text => stop_year).click
    find('.ui-datepicker-month').click
    find('option', :text => stop_month).click
    find('.ui-state-default', :text => stop_day, :match => :prefer_exact).click
  end
  find('input[value="Go"]').click
  date_picker = find('.timespanperiod').text
  start_date, end_date = date_picker.split(" - ")
  start_formatted = Date.strptime("#{start_date}",'%d/%m/%Y')
  end_formatted = Date.strptime("#{end_date}",'%d/%m/%Y')
  start_formatted.should eq (Date.strptime("#{arg1}",'%m/%d/%Y'))
  end_formatted.should eq (Date.strptime("#{arg2}",'%m/%d/%Y'))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `find(".active.day").click` after `fill_in` worked for me:

```
within("#dates_form") do
  fill_in "datepicker_mini", :with => "01/01/2010"
  find(".active.day").click
  fill_in "datepicker_maxi", :with => "01/01/2020"
  find(".active.day").click
end
```